# Can I mine out a big dark place under my village for mobs to spawn in rather than the unlit areas up in the village?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

So I lit up my village pretty well but there are still some spots that zombies, creepers or skeletons spawn in. An idea popped into my mind - can I just mine out a dark place under the village within a certain range that mobs will spawn in rather than spawning up in the village?

I couldnt really find anything related to this online so any people that have tried this could you confirm if this is possible or not?

Comment: Look into building a mob switch instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having a large dark area — such as a mob farm — is a good way to *decrease* the spawn rates elsewhere, which is particularly useful when you've explored and lit up all the caves in an area (which will tend to concentrate the monsters in any remaining dark spots).

However, it will not ensure that *no* zombies ever spawn in your village and attack your villagers. And monsters despawn when you're too far away, so when you approach again, if the village comes in range before the dark area does, monsters will spawn in the village first.

Answer (score 0):

Mobs spawn in a radius around the player. They can and will spawn in any viable area. Additionally, they will despawn randomly as well, meaning you can’t simply trap them in an area and expect no new mobs to ever spawn. There are a few exceptions to this, but they are very difficult to achieve in survival.

You are far better off simply lighting up your village area and building a wall to protect it as there are no other reliable ways to control mob spawning to that degree.

Answer (score 0):

In Minecraft Java Edition, there is a mob cap mechanics where if too many mobs of a category (for example; hostile mobs) are in the same loaded chunks, then new mobs of that category wouldn't be able to spawn within your loaded chunks. Although the amount of chunks you have loaded, and whether or not you're in multiplayer (where multiple people's loaded chunks could be loaded and overlapped) will affect your mob cap, your typical mob cap in a singleplayer world is around 70 mobs of that category type.

Within the loaded chunks around the 70 mobs, no hostile mobs should spawn in around that range, but while you're outside of that area and only have the surrounding area loaded in, I would recommend having some more iron golems spread throughout the village.

Edit: removed misinformation about name-tagged monsters counting towards the mob cap

Comment: Nametagged mobs don't count towards a mob cap. Neither do ones that picked up items, sit in boats or minecarts, and generally most situations where they are kept from despawning. There are precious few methods to keep a persistent hostile mob in the mob cap.

Comment: Ah, my mistake.